# Optimising a mysql statement

Tags: mysql

i have a table with around 1 128 910 rows and now my SQL statement is starting to run very slow.

My table looks like this:

```
SU_Id   SU_User SU_Skill SU_Value SU_Date
int(10) int(10) int(10)  float    int(10)
1       1       23       45.34    1300978612
2       1       23       48.51    1300978865
3       1       23       47.21    1300979203
4       3       23       61.01    1300979245
5       2       23       38.93    1300979412
6       1       17       12.76    1300979712
7       2       23       65.30    1300979998
```

As seen in SU_Skill a user can have more then one entry with the same skill number. SU_Value hold the value of a skill, it can go up and down. SU_Date holds the date when a value was added.

I want a SQL statement that selects the 20 currently highest values of a skill. The following SQL statement is what i use today but it is slow and i think there is a better way of doing it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT SU_User AS Player,
(SELECT SU_Value FROM WOU__SkillUploads WHERE SU_User = Player AND SU_Skill = 23 ORDER BY SU_Date DESC LIMIT 1) AS Value
FROM WOU__SkillUploads
WHERE SU_Skill = 23
ORDER BY Value DESC LIMIT 20
```

Is there a faster way? Thanks for reading my question!

Comment: You need to post the output of `EXPLAIN` statement, you need to post `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and if possible `SHOW VARIABLES` output too plus the hardware that you're using. Also, you need to specify what slow means. 1 second? 10 seconds? 5 minutes?

Comment: The output of EXPLAIN is:

    id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra
    1  PRIMARY  WOU__SkillUploads  ALL  NULL NULL NULL NULL 1128910  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
    2  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  WOU__SkillUploads  ALL  NULL NULL NULL NULL 1128910  Using where; Using filesort

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE is: CREATE TABLE `WOU__SkillUploads` (
  `SU_Id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SU_User` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `SU_Skill` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `SU_Value` float NOT NULL,
  `SU_Date` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SU_Id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1131789 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sub-selects are very slow, especially in the way you're using this.

Rewrite this as a JOIN. In this case, because you want all records from SkillUploads where SU_SKILL = 23, this should probably be a RIGHT JOIN.

Comment: Ok, i will try to look in to that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can the same user be in the results multiple times?  This may work for you.

```
SELECT SU_USER, MAX(SU_VALUE)
FROM WOU_SKILLUploads
WHERE SU_SKILL=23
GROUP BY SU_USER
ORDER BY MAX(SU_VALUE) DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: No, each user can only show one time. This SQL will not show if a user have a lower skill in the last upload then the one before.